# line-clamp not working in mobile view for firefox and also in safari browser iphone

Tags: html, css, angular

line-clamp is not working in safari browser for iphone and in mobile view of firefox.

This is my code

html in angular:

```
<div class="clip_text_2_line" [innerHTML]="viewdata.company_desc | sainitizeHtml"></div>
```

My Css

```
.clip_text_2_line{
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: clip!important;
    display: -webkit-box!important;
    line-clamp: 2!important;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2!important;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical!important;
}
```

The incoming data is from text editor, so will contain html content, thats why i had to use `innerHTML` and `sainitizeHtml`.
The data may contain Engilsh or Japanese characters.

Here is what it looks like.

[image]

You can see in the top portion, the text is breaking with `...` and then it continues again.

It works fine in moto g5 plus and other devices, as given below.
This is what i expect all devices to show.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Safari/Firefox adds a margin. Add the following css.

```
.clip_text_2_line > p {
    margin: 0;
}
```